# Sliding div onclick left/right

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Provided below is a snippet from my html and css code, how and what would I need to add in not only html and css, but javascript as well to make this work as a slide in/out in the direction of (right to open) and (left to close) div?

I currently do not have any javascript written up for this as I do not know where to start with it...I am, however, using jquery-1.3.2

If anyone can provide a jsfiddle, I'd greatly appreciate it ;)

**HTML**

```
<div id="left">
    <a href="#">Edit Profile</a>
    <a href="#">Settings</a>
    <a href="?logoff">Sign Out</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left { width: 338px; border-left: 1px solid #333; float: left; }
#left a {
  width: 145px;
  height: 22px;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.09);
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 34px;
  color: #15ADFF;
  font: 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #000, 2px 2px 3px rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.7);
}
#left a:hover {
  width: 138px;
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.4);
  border-right: 7px solid #15ADFF;
  color: #111;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
```

I'm assuming I'd need to add an id or class as either `#open`, `#close` and/or `.open`, `.close`.

Comment: JAVA != JAVASCRIPT!!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery's animate function, should do the job easy enough.

Tutorial/Information on .animate:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/understanding-jquery-animate-function/

Comment: yes I don't think we should be just writing people's code for them either.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't enough info here to know what you want, because the layout of the page is important. Without knowing if the menu should be absolute, fixed or relative.

You can use jQuery's animate() method to animate CSS numeric properties, and then use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to slide the menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingmedia/8a7GL/1/

It's only 2 lines of code.